# Fibonacci Sequence logic in Python

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

A tutorial I am going through had the following program

```
# This program calculates the Fibonacci sequence
a = 0
b = 1
count = 0
max_count = 20
while count < max_count:
    count = count + 1
    old_a = a    # we need to keep track of a since we change it
    print(old_a,end=" ")   # Notice the magic end=" " in the print function arguments that
                           # keeps it from creating a new line
    a = b
    b = old_a + b
print() # gets a new (empty) line
```

The code is perfect. However, I am not able to figure out how the sequence is calculated.
How are the values changed to create the sequence?

Comment: Your code formatting is broken. Good [Fibonacci related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/499245/923794) are already aplenty on this site. Getting your code explained or discussed is not a good question format for this site. Please read at least the first two paragraphs of [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

It'll make more sense if you remove all of that extraneous code:

```
while count < max_count:
    old_a = a
    a = b
    b = old_a + b
```

The `old_a` is probably confusing you. It's the long way of writing this:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

Which swaps `a` with `b` and (at the same time), `b` with `a + b`. Note that it *isn't* the same as writing:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

Because by the time you re-define `b`, `a` already holds its new value, which is equal to `b`.

I'd also run through the code manually by writing it out on paper.

Comment: Hello Blender,Can you give me full code for the sequence. because i tried with the code you given but got error.

Comment: @thoufiq: I'm sure you can figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
a, b = 0, 1
for _ in range(20):
        print a
        a, b = b, a+b
```